# PhpStorm Move Caret to Next Blank Line

Tags: cursor, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, code-navigation

I'm used to the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl DOWN` in many editors that will jump the caret (cursor) to the next blank line in the code. This allows for quick navigation of the code.

Perhaps I completely missed it, but the action of "move caret to next blank line" or something like that is not in the Keymap list for the editor.

Do you know if such an option is there, and if not, can you recommend a good way to navigate the code? "Move Caret to Code Block Start" is not very intuitive to me when I'm moving about the code and the simple page-up, page-down are too coarse.

Edit: As @CrazyCoder says, this feature does not appear to be available. I've added a [ticket for it on YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-7480?projectKey=IDEA). If you are also interested in this feature, please vote it up.

Comment: Your request was implemented for IntelliJ IDEA 15. It works when you use the Emacs key mapping.

Comment: @engineer do you know what is the name of this action in the intellij idea keymap settings so that I can associate a shortcut to move caret to next blank line ?

Comment: @Moebius , *Move Caret Forward a Pragraph* & *Move Caret Backward a Pragraph*. They are under **File > Settings... > Keymap**. It's not quite "to Next Blank Line", because if there are 2 consecutive empty lines and you are on the first one, it won't go to the second one. Notice that this line will appear with the default key mapping only if you are on Emacs key mapping. Otherwise the key mapping is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such feature in PhpStorm (and in IntelliJ IDEA platform that it's based on) and surprisingly no one has requested it yet. Feel free to [add your feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

If you are looking for the list of the most common navigation shortcuts, refer to the **Default Keymap Reference** that you can open from the Welcome screen, print, fold into a pyramid and put on your desk.

Answer (score 5):

Since the 10/09/2015, there is the functions `move caret backward a paragraph` and `move caret forward a paragraph` ([source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-74158)).